# Newton backward interpolation in Mathematica

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I have the following task:

> Create a function (in Wolfram Mathematica), called $\mathrm{NewtonBackward}$[n_,x0_,h_,f_] which interpolates backwards the function $f(x)$ with nodes {x_i = x_0 + $i$$\cdot$ h, where $i$ = 0,..,n}.

The parameters of NewtonBackwards function are:

- n_  :number of nodes
- x0_ :starting node
- h_  :the difference between neighbouring nodes
- f_  :this is the function f(x), for example we can take f(x) = E^x

There is also another restriction - I am not allowed to use the built in functions of Wolfram Mathematica for finding sum or product (like Sum[f,{i,Subscript[i, max]}] ).
Can anybody tell me how to do this ???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's very unlikely that it will get accepted at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
NewtonBackward[n_,x0_,h_,f_]:= Interpolation[Table[{x,f[x]},{x,x0,x0+n h,h}]]; 
Plot[NewtonBackward[10, 0, 1/10, E^# &][x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for this. But actually I forgot to mention about another restriction in the solution - it has to be iterative... Does this mean we should use some kind of a cycle, for example "Do[]"?

Comment: @guest If someone is telling you that you've to program iterative functions in Mathematica, tell her/him to learn before teaching. Reference http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193

Comment: I'll ask him about this, but how can I make the NewtonBackward[] function visualize the Lagrange polynom (that we have built by interpolating backward) ??

Comment: @guest take a look at the help for `InterpolatingPolynomial[]`, which is the lagrange interpolator

Comment: @belisarius It's likely that the guy is learning numerical analysis with Mathematica. Maybe it's not nice to program loops in Mathematica, but it's nice to learn how black boxes (like Mathematica) work. I have also seen numerical analysis courses in Matlab, though it's also very inefficient to do loops in Matlab. Here, the important is learning, not speed. And honnestly, I don't think it would be wise to teach numerical analysis in C or Fortran for a first course. Clean syntax, read-eval loop, nice GUI and plotting capabilities are far better.